# TICKET_CREATE privileges - Can't create a ticket on the tracker

Tags: torsocks, tor-install, censorship

I have a problem regarding a specific package (obfs-proxy) which for some reason is not availabe anymore(at least not on archlinux anyway) and wanted to create a ticket on the trac but apparently I don't have enough rights to do it as I'm getting the following message:

> TICKET_CREATE privileges are required to perform this operation on
>   Ticket #None. You don't have the required permissions.

Why is this happening?

For clarification the reason I want this package is because the only way I can access tor is through bridges and I need to add it to my torrc so I can use torsocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tor Project is currently in the process of migrating from trac to a Gitlab instance. It may be difficult to report issues there for the next few weeks. Instead you can try mailing lists, or asking on the #tor IRC channel at OFTC.

But for your actual question, I don't think that the Tor Project is the maintainer of the tor or obfs4proxy packages on Arch.

Comment: I use irc with tor but since now I need bridges for torsocks I can't go #tor hence I came here. but yeah, i'll wait a few weeks then

Comment: If you have the Tor Browser, you can always use the obfs4 proxy from there (`tor-browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Tor/PluggableTransports/obfs4proxy`) with your system tor until you get the package working again.